# WCF duplex channel, de-coupling the request and the response

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, duplex, durable-duplex

I'm contemplating a project where I'll be required to make use of what is variously called the "asynchronous" mode, or the "duplex" mode, or the "callback" mode of SOAP webservice. In this mode, the caller of the service provides in the SOAP header a "reply-to" address, and the service, instead of returning the output of the call in the HTTP response, creates a separate HTTP connection to this "reply-to" address and posts the response message to it. This is normally achieved in WCF using a CompositeDuplexBinding, like so:

```
<binding name="async_http_text">
    <compositeDuplex clientBaseAddress="http://192.168.10.123:1234/async" />
    <oneWay />
    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10" />
    <httpTransport useDefaultWebProxy="false" />
</binding>
```

This results in not one, but two HTTP connections per call: one from the client to the service, and then one from the service back to the client. From the point of view of the service implementation, nothing changes, you have a method that implements the interface method, and you take in the request and return the response. Fantastic, this is what I need, almost.

In my situation, the request and response can be separated by anything from minutes to days. I need a way to decouple the request and the response, and "store" the state (message, response URI, whatever) until I have enough information to respond at a later time (or even never, under certain circumstances).

I'm not terribly excited about having my methods essentially "paused" for up to days at a time, along with the required silly timeout values (if they're even accepted as valid), but I don't know how to go about putting a system like this together.

In order to be completely clear, I'm implementing a set of standards provided by a standards body, so I do not have flexibility to change SOAP message semantics or alter protocol implementations. This sort of interaction is exactly what was intended when the ReplyTo header was implemented in WS-Addressing.

How would you do it? Perhaps Workflow Foundation enables this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the Windows Workflow Foundation (v4) does indeed facilitate this sort of message exchange.

Because WF allows you to decouple the request and response, and do basically whatever you want in the middle, including persist the workflow, idle it, and go outside and cut the grass, you get this capability "for free". Information can be found at these URLs:

[Durable Duplex (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662960%28VS.100%29.aspx)

[Workflow 4 Services and duplex communications](http://www.develop.com/wf4duplex)

Answer (score 1):

In such case don't use HTTP duplex communication as defined in WCF. It will simply not work because it is dependent on some other prerequisities - session, service instance living on the server, etc. It all adds a lot of problems with timeouts.

What you need is bi-directional communication based on fact that service exposes one way service and client exposes one way service as well (services can be two-way to support some kind of delivery notification). You will pass client's address in the first request as well as some correlation Id to differ multiple requests passed from the same client. You will call client service when the request is completed. Yes, you will have to manage all the stuff by yourselves.

If you are in intranet environment and your clients will be Windows based you can even think about changing your transport protocol to MSMQ because it has built-in support for all these requirements.

**Edit:**

I checked your updated question and you would call your communication pattern as Soap Messaging. I have never did it with WCF but it should be possible. You need to expose service on both sides of the communication - you can build your service to exactly follow needed contracts. When your service receives call you can use `OperationContext.Current.IncommingMessageHeaders` to access WS-Addressing information. You can store this information and use them later if you need them. The problem is that these information will not contain what you need. You have to fill them first on the client. This is generally possible by using `OperationContextScope` and filling `OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders`. What I'm affraid is that WCF can be "to clever" and override your changes to outgoing WS-Addressing information. I will probably try it myself during weekend.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have control over protocols, nor do I have control over service contracts. These are given to me by government-funded standards bodies.

Comment: @Mark: What does it mean that you don't have control over service contracts and protocols? Does it mean that your other party will use WCF with WsDualHttpBinding? Because if not you can't use it neither.

Comment: @Ladislav: I mean I can't use MSMQ, and I can't "pass the client's address in the first request". I cannot change single thing about the interactions, whatsoever. They are an established standard, and my software is only on one end of the conversation.

Comment: @Mark: So you can't probably use WsDualHttpBinding because it demands its own communication exchange patterns - it sits on top of WS-ReliabeSession which has to be supported by both sides - it creates plenty of additional infrastructure requests.

Comment: @Mark: You should modify your question and describe what you can do and what you can't. You should also mention what you have control over - server, client, contracts (service, callback, messages, data), etc. Also mention platforms of all related parties.

Comment: @Ladislav: I did, after your first comment.